# too many open files for my server on OS X

Tags: networking, mac-osx

I'm getting the error "too many open files".  It appears to happen when by process has around 256 simultaneous connections.  If I do

```
sysctl -A | grep maxfiles
```

I see:

```
kern.maxfiles = 12288
kern.maxfilesperproc = 10240
```

My server is managed by launchd.  Do I also need to set the NumberOfFiles option in the plist file?

Comment: Number of files opened by what?  Is this a shared drive letter than too many remote are connecting to, what is your situation?

Comment: This is probably related to the ulimit settings (ulimit -n)

Comment: I had this issue when a program was trying to install an application in a corrupted .pkg file.  Under what circumstances do you get the error?

Answer (score 1):

Default limit setting for bash on OSX looks like 256.

So, as Joe says:

**ulimit** -n x

Where x can be a higher number.

You might want to add that to the start script of the process when you run it, or to your .bashrc to make it more permanent.

**lsof** will let you see what each file is, although files in this context are also network connections, pipes, as well as actual files.